# Sometimes the editor doesn't work for making a word as BOLD

Tags: support, editor

When trying to make a word as BOLD, the editor toolbar doesn't worked as intended.

I have experienced this several times by pressing the "B" icon button on the editor toolbar, however that didn't work either.

Comment: More details are needed to reproduce this.

Comment: We need example and way to reproduce otherwise best we can do is guessing.

Comment: May I Know Why down vote..?? Its what have i experienced.

Comment: It's already been explained in the comments.

Comment: You're a software developer according to your profile. If you received a bug report that simply said "sometimes bold doesn't work" what would your reaction to be?

Comment: The downvotes (at least my own) are because you ignore comments and refuse to help up help you.

Comment: So sorry guys, I was not getting any notifications. I was not actually ignoring the comments. The question is regarding when we type answers in stackoverflow, making a word / sentence was not working for me.

Answer (score 9):

I guess you refer to your [lastest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16785621/447356) and you tried to mark a word which is part of the quoted text?

In such case it indeed won't work, as you marked the text as **code** which means whatever you put there is shown as-is including the `**` used to mark as bold.

This is by design of course and to "solve" it mark such text as **quote** instead then you can bold words.

Comment: It's wrong to use code formatting for something that isn't code anyway.

Comment: +1 for actually being able to pull out some meaning from this impossibly vague question :P

Comment: @Doorknob just a guess and I'm really puzzled why the OP doesn't bother to clarify...

Comment: So sorry guys, I was not getting any notifications. I was not actually ignoring the comments. The question is regarding when we type answers in stackoverflow, making a word / sentence was not working for me. Thank you @ShadowWizard

Comment: @Jyothu Never too late I guess, even 5+ years later.... so all is solved by now?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I had done an upvote for your answer and left there only.  Today i got a notification for the downvote. Then only i came to know about all these comments. And Yes, It was resolved. :)